# How to load file in sagemaker custom deploy endpoint script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy a sentiment analysis model on sagemaker to an endpoint to predict sentiment in real time of an input text. This model will take a single text String as input and return the sentiment.

To train the xgboost model, I followed this  [notebook](https://github.com/NadimKawwa/sagemaker_ml/blob/master/SageMaker_IMDB_highlevel.ipynb) upto step 23. 
This uploaded model.tar.gz to s3 bucket. I additionally uploaded vocabulary_dict generated by sklearn's CountVectorizer(to create bag of words)to s3 bucket as well.

To deploy this pre-trained model, I can use [this method](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_sklearn.html#deploying-endpoints-from-model-data) and supply an entry point python file predict.py.

```
sklearn_model = SKLearnModel(model_data="s3://bucket/model.tar.gz", role="SageMakerRole", entry_point="predict.py")
```

Documentation says that I have to provide model.tar.gz only as argument and it will be loaded in model_fn. But if I am writing my own model_fn, how do I load the model then? If I put additional files in the same directory as of model.tar.gz in S3, can I load them as well?

Now to do the classification, I will have to vectorize the input text before calling model.predict(bow_vector) in the method predict_fn. In order to do that, I need word_dict which I prepared during pre-processing training data and wrote to s3.

My question is how do I get the word_dict inside the model_fn? Can I load it from s3? 
Below is code for predict.py.

```
import os
import re
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sagemaker_containers

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer



def model_fn(model_dir):

    #TODO How to load the word_dict.
    #TODO How to load the model.
    return model, word_dict

def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    print('Inferring sentiment of input data.')
    trained_model, word_dict = model
    if word_dict is None:
        raise Exception('Model has not been loaded properly, no word_dict.')

    #Process input_data so that it is ready to be sent to our model.

    input_bow_csv = process_input_text(word_dict, input_data)
    prediction = trained_model.predict(input_bow_csv)
    return prediction


def process_input_text(word_dict, input_data):

    words = text_to_words(input_data);
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=lambda x: x, tokenizer=lambda x: x, word_dict)
    bow_array = vectorizer.transform([words]).toarray()[0]
    bow_csv = ",".join(str(bit) for bit in bow_array)
    return bow_csv

def text_to_words(text):
    """
    Uses the Porter Stemmer to stem words in a review
    """
    #instantiate stemmer
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    text_nohtml = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").get_text() # Remove HTML tags
    text_lower = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ", text_nohtml.lower()) # Convert to lower case
    words = text_lower.split() # Split string into words
    words = [w for w in words if w not in stopwords.words("english")] # Remove stopwords
    words = [PorterStemmer().stem(w) for w in words] # stem
    return words

def input_fn(input_data, content_type):
    return input_data;

def output_fn(prediction_output, accept):
    return prediction_output;
```